# Issues when decrypting data received from GET python

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, odoo-9, payment-processing

I am developing a new `payment_acquirer` module for Odoo, and since last week, I am always getting an error when I try to decrypt data that I received through the server.

When I copy the data in an another python file to test, it seems to be working perfectly with the same data, but when I do it in my controller, it returns an error.

This is the code inside my controller :

```
@http.route('/payment/ariarynet/result', type='http', auth="none", methods=['POST', 'GET'], csrf=False)
def ariarynet_result(self, **post):
    """ Handle Ariary.net response and redirect to form_validate"""
    _logger.info('Beginning Ariary.net form_feedback with post data %s', pprint.pformat(post))  # debug
    key = bytes("477c3551da64136491eff1cb6ab27be35093b2512eb78f2c8d"[:24])
    params = dict(post)
    raw = b"%s"%post.get('idpanier')
    decode = raw.encode('utf8')
    idpanier = main.Utils().decrypt(key,decode) #it return an error
```

When executed, I have the following error:

```
raise ValueError("Invalid data length, data must be a multiple of " + str(self.block_size) + " bytes\n.")

ValueError: Invalid data length, data must be a multiple of 8 bytes
```

I am using pyDes module to crypt and decrypt data.

This is the test that is working :

```
def test_bytes(self):
    key = bytes("477c3551da64136491eff1cb6ab27be35093b2512eb78f2c8d"[:24])
    expect = "12177"
    raw = "%8E%16%B8n%A6%1F%2Fj" #this is the data that I copied from the url
    text = urllib.unquote(raw)
    byteArray = bytes(text)
    print Utils().decrypt(key, text)
    self.assertEqual(expect,Utils().decrypt(key, text), "%s est diférent de %s" % (expect, Utils().decrypt(key, text)) )
```

I really need your help to figure out what am I doing wrong.

**Update:**
I think that the probleme have to do with the character encoding, because when I am trying to compare the data I get with the excpected one, I don't get the same thing:

```
param = post.get('idpanier')
text = (param.encode('utf8'))
print "utf8 encode %s, hex encoded text %s" % (text, text.encode('hex'))
print "utf8 encode %s, hex encoded text %s" % ("b4227475d651420b".decode('hex'), "b4227475d651420b") #excpected behavior
```

Here is the output:

```
utf8 encode �"tu�QB
               , hex encoded text efbfbd227475efbfbd51420b
utf8 encode �"tu�QB
               , hex encoded text b4227475d651420b
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found : instead of retriving parameters with post.get(), I have manage to get the real parameters data through the incoming url directly, where parameters encoding is not changed yet.

```
query = parse_qs("http://url?%s"%request.httprequest.query_string) #append the query string to a dummy url to get a well formed url
param = query.get('idpanier')
```

After that, everything worked fine.